# How to use an Openstreetmap file in Android application

Tags: android, openstreetmap, mapnik

I have a customized map file "map.osm", how I can use that file to create an Android Openstreet map navigator App?
And where I need to import that file in my eclipse project folder?

Please let me know the process to load a map. At present I have done this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private MapView m_mapView;
    private int MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private double MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE = 38.535350;
    private double MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = -121.753807;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.osm_map);
        m_mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        m_mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        m_mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        m_mapView.setClickable(true);
        m_mapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
        m_mapView.getController().setZoom(MAP_DEFAULT_ZOOM);
        m_mapView.getController().setCenter(
            new GeoPoint(MAP_DEFAULT_LATITUDE, MAP_DEFAULT_LONGITUDE));
        m_mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);      
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

So I don't how to load map in to that. Please help. Now I'm getting blank map.
[image]

Comment: Where exactly did you get map.osm from? What does it contain? What Java library can you use to read it?

Comment: the osm file given by my customer, he want that map in the androip app, its a kind of xml file, I can open it in notepad

Comment: and the file starting something like, "<osm version="0.6" generator="CGImap 0.2.0" copyright="OpenStreetMap and contributors" attribution="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" license="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/">"

Comment: I'm doing this first time, please help me

Comment: What information does it contain and what exactly do you want to display?

Comment: You need to tell us, what your app needs to realize with this geodata: rendering map, address lookup, POI search, routing, giving directions, ...

Comment: Actually, its map for zoo, they have marked everything in the map, so I need to use that map in Android app

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use map.osm xml file in osmdroid instead of default online map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20702907/how-to-use-map-osm-xml-file-in-osmdroid-instead-of-default-online-map)