# How to use map.osm xml file in osmdroid instead of default online map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have received a customized osm file (map.osm) from my customer to integrate Android project,  but I don't know how to use that file, usually I'm using

```
mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
```

So, how I can use the map.osm file my android project.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but AFAIK it doesn't work like that. A Tilesource is a rendered raster map of geodata. Thus you need to render the data first in a local renderer, for example [Maperiative](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) or [TileMill](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill). They can create a tile folder structure output, that can be used by OSMdroid instead of the official tile sources: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/wiki/HowToUsePackager